# how to present another viewController in separate UIWindow

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I want to create a Floating Button in my app which will be visible all over the page and can handle the event from a separate ViewController to maintain the button state.

I want to open a ViewController from a separate window at the same time when the user login into the app. And if the user clicks on the button then ViewController will handle the event and if click outside the button then it should handle by the main controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Create a UIViwe with a .xib file and create your required UI. All UI-related functions will be there in UIView class and for action create a manager class that manages all events.

Use the below code to add playerView to the window

```
PlayerManager.shared.addPlayer()
```

See bellow code for playerManager class

```
class PlayerManager : NSObject{
  static let shared = PlayerManager()
  private override init(){
    super.init()
  }

    func addPlayer(){
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        let player = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PlayerView", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! PlayerView
        let outerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: getXValueForView(width: 180), y: getYValueForView(height: 120), width: 180, height: 60))
        player.frame.size = CGSize(width: 180, height: 60)
        player.playerDelegate = self
        outerView.clipsToBounds = true
        player.miniPlayer.isHidden = false
        player.expendedPlayer.isHidden = true
        outerView.addSubview(player)
        window?.addSubview(outerView)
    }
}
```